# Delphi IDE opens a simple text file as a binary file. Text view needed

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I want to customize a simple text file with Delphi IDE. The view in Delphi Sydney takes getting used to.
[image]

How can I convince the IDE to show me the text? Switching from Binary (Binär) to Ansi is unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2):

Your text file is clearly in UTF-16 LE without BOM.

Apparently, RAD Studio doesn't recognise this as a text file.

**Solutions:**

1. The best solution is to not use UTF-16 at all -- that's a strange encoding. Use UTF-8 instead.
2. Alternatively, it seems like RAD Studio *does* recognise the file's encoding if you add the UTF-16 LE BOM.

Comment: The IDE relies on a BOM for non-ANSI encoded files. Otherwise you have to select the correct encoding manually. That is probably the same with UTF-8.

Comment: @UweRaabe: Just tried a UTF-8 sans BOM, and it opened correctly in RAD Studio.

Comment: Indeed! There seems to be some UTF-8 detection at work.

Comment: I'd have expected the IDE to call [`IsTextUnicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-istextunicode) notwithstanding the fact that such a function cannot be implemented such that it is 100% accurate in its diagnoses.

Comment: You cannot correct it manually either. If you have to correct this e.g. via notpad++, then you can also continue to work with notpad++.

Comment: Doesn't it work when you select UTF-16 LE instead Binär?

Comment: Just open the file in _Notepad_ (aka _Editor_), then choose "Save as..." and select "Unicode" as encoding - that should write UTF-16 LE with BOM. Every _Windows_ installation comes with this program and worked like this since at least NT5. (And yes, its name is not "Notpad".)